# How to show line count in codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I am using codemirror API in my application, i tried to show the total line count and when type to count new line but it was giving me another thing

I use this script to get the last-child of number, but when i have 29 lines it show this **1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829** which is not what i intent to do i want it to show just **29** and also onkeydown is not working at all

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var tolalline = $('.CodeMirror-linenumber:last-child').text();
      $('#hcunter').text(tolalline);
      $('#inputTextToSave').keydown(function(){
        var tolalline = $('.CodeMirror-linenumber:last-child').text();
        $('#hcunter').text(tolalline);
      }
                                  );
      $("#alterTool").click(function(){
        $("#EditTool").toggle(1000);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

CodeMirror

```
<script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("inputTextToSave"), 
    {
        lineNumbers: true,
        viewportMargin: Infinity,
        //Theme
        styleActiveLine: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        gutter: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get numbers of lines you must use the css selector:

```
.CodeMirror-code > div:last-child div.CodeMirror-gutter-elt
```

So, if you want to count the lines, you will override the Enter key in extraKeys attribute of CodeMirror configuration. It would be:

```
  extraKeys:
  {
    Enter: function(){
      setTimeout(function() {
        var tolalline = $('.CodeMirror-code > div:last-child div.CodeMirror-gutter-elt').text();
        $('#hcunter').text(tolalline);
      }, 0);
      return CodeMirror.Pass;
    }
  }
```

I set a setTimeout to create a minimun delay necessary. You don't need to set a onKeyDown event now.

All code:

```
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("inputTextToSave"),
      {
        lineNumbers: true,
        viewportMargin: Infinity,
        //Theme
        styleActiveLine: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        gutter: true,
        extraKeys:
        {
          Enter: function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
              var tolalline = $('.CodeMirror-code > div:last-child div.CodeMirror-gutter-elt').text();
              $('#hcunter').text(tolalline);
            }, 0);
            return CodeMirror.Pass;
          }
        }
      }
    );


$(document).ready(function(){
  var tolalline = $('.CodeMirror-code > div:last-child div.CodeMirror-gutter-elt').text();
  $('#hcunter').text(tolalline);
  $("#alterTool").click(function(){
    $("#EditTool").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

I hope that it's that you wanted! :-)